# Android: how to populate GridView from read SD Card Folder images?

Tags: android, image, gridview, gallery, photo

I have a part of code which search my folders, which have images. Can somebody show me how to add them to GridView and how after using OnItemClickListener to show images in them?

```
      public static List<File> findImageDirectories(File parentDirectory){

List<File> directories = new ArrayList<File>();

if (parentDirectory.listFiles() != null){

    for (File file: parentDirectory.listFiles()){
        // If the parentDirectory contains an image file
        if (isImageFile(file)){
            directories.add(parentDirectory);
            break;
        }
        // If it contains a subfolder, check the subfolder as well
        else if (file.isDirectory()){
            findImageDirectories(file);
        }               
    }
}

return directories;        


private static boolean isImageFile(File f) {
    String name = f.getName();
    if (name.endsWith(".jpg") || name.endsWith(".png"))
    // Add other formats as desired
    {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: This code allows a user to pick a single image.

Comment: ouuupps. Then, can you say plz  how to get a folders which have images (same like in android gallery)??

Comment: There are many tutorials out there, you can easily google it.

Comment: Yes i saw them, but found nothing that i need. I added another code in my "question". Can you see plz and say how to add it to GridView??

Comment: hey, if you have any tutorial or example, can you give link?